# How to install pimcore on linux

Tags: pimcore

Hi Guys I have a linux OS with follwoing configurations
1. RHEL 6.6
2. PHP 5.16
3. apache server 2.7.15
4. Mysql 5.6.13 does it's sufficient to install
the pimcore I tried using the link https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-pimcore-on-a-centos-7-vps/   but couldn't succeed could you tell me where I am wrong or what should I do to install pimcore

Comment: You really need to share more details on error messages, what is happening and so on for us to be able to help you here.

Answer (score 2):

Your apache and mysql version's are fine but php version needs to be upgraded as

Minimum server requirement for pimcore 4 is

- Apache >= 2.2
- PHP >= 5.5
- MySQL / MariaDB >= version 5.5.3

https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/System+Requirements

Minimum server requirement for pimcore 3 is

- Apache >= 2.2
- PHP >= 5.4
- MySQL / MariaDB >= version 5.5

https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE3/System+Requirements

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: Hi I have PHP 5.5.16 but still not able to install could you tell me where I am wrong

Comment: Have you created the virtual host, restarted the apache
what exactly you get when you try to hit virtual host url?

Comment: Yeah Bhupinder I did that and when i hit the link I used to get No Sponsors page  for yourdomain.com

Comment: just to work now i Installed pimcore on windows 7 could you tell me how to import large csv files more than 5 mb's bcaz i can't import csv files greater tah 2 mb

Comment: I got the solution for uploading the file of size more than 2 mb

Comment: Good to see that you found solutions. Great :)